# Create a stream using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm having this problem with puppeteer, I want to generate a pdf based on a html page, and when it's completed, I want to return the path to the file, then I'm using a aws s3 bucket to upload the file to aws based on the path it's created on.

My code:

```
  const generatePDF = (html) => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      
      await page.setContent(html)
      await page.emulateMediaType('screen')
      await page.pdf({
        path: path/to/pdf
        format: 'A4'
      })

      await browser.close()
}
```

And in this case I can just return the path, and locally it will work. But on a server it won't work, because the path can't be resolved. And what I'm trying to do is use `page.pdf()` without a specified path, create a stream and when it's completed I want to return the path to the file. Any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

it's always better to make use of Nodes `Path` module, when you deal with the filesystem.
That should fix your problem.

```
const generatePDF = (html) => {
    const path = require('path');
    
    const pdfPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/pdf');      
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      
      await page.setContent(html)
      await page.emulateMediaType('screen')
      await page.pdf({
        path: pdfPath
        format: 'A4'
      })

      await browser.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the directory name by

Add `process.cwd()` before the Reletive Path

For Example

```
filePath: process.cwd() + "/screenshots/" + 'name_of_pdf'+".pdf"
```

I'm not sure how exactly the AWS s3 bucket is. But this should work